Two distinct logging configurations in one program
I am trying to have two separate loggers. One that writes to a file and another that writes to a stdout.
The file logger, needs to be passed onwards to a separate module. While the stdout logs the main program.
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='log.log', filemode='a', format="%(asctime)s - %(lineno)d - %(message)s", level=logging.DEBUG)
log_file = logging.getLogger('another_program')

logging.basicConfig(format="%(asctime)s - %(lineno)d - %(message)s", level=logging.ERROR)
log_stdout = logging.getLogger('main')

log_stdout.info('This should be stdout, from main program')
another_program(logger=log_file) # Logs from inside should be written to log.log

However, everyone just seems to be going to stdout. Its possibly because logging.basicConfig cant have multiple configs for the same program? If yes, how else can I get two separate loggers as I want?

Does this answer your question? Python logging multiple modules each module log to separate files

basicConfig can only be called once (second call is ignored). two separate loggers is not basic, so you need to set up your loggers and handlers individually. Check out the python logging cookbook in the official documentation.

Does this answer your question? Changing logging's 'basicConfig' which is already set
